# How to write a PromQL unit test to check that an alarm doesn't fire?

Tags: promql

I'm starting to write unit tests for Prometheus PromQL alerts using `promtool test rules`. Basic tests work, but I'd also like to write tests that check whether an alarm *didn't* fire for a certain series of values.

Is this possible and how would I express such a test?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have figured it out.

Just provide an empty exp_alerts in the test:

```
evaluation_interval: 1m
tests:
  - interval: 10s
    input_series:
    - series: '...'
      values: '...'
    alert_rule_test: 
      - eval_time: 10m
        alertname: my_alert
        exp_alerts:
```

This will pass if there are no alerts, and will fail if alerts fired.